# PHP - returning a variable variable from a function scope

Tags: php, function, scope, return-value, variable-variables

Is there a way to return a [variable variable](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) from a function?

This is what I tried:

```
function varvar($num){
    $var = "foo".$num;
    return $$var;
}
varvar(3);
echo $foo3;
```

But nothing prints out. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to capture the return value in a variable:

```
function varvar($num){
    $var = "foo".$num;
    return $$var;
}
$foo3 = varvar(3);
echo $foo3;
```